# Can I run mariadb's docker with a mariadb-server local installation?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm trying run on docker a mariadb instance with specific port because I ready have a mariadb server run on the same server on default port (3306).
I'm using the following command

```
docker run --name mariadb_develop -p 3307:3307 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=superpass -d mariadb -v /var/lib/mysql-develop:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

but if I try to connect to 3307 port `mysql -uroot -psuperpass -P3307` I'm connecting to mariadb server, not to mariadb's docker.

Can I run mariadb's docker with a mariadb-server local installation?

Comment: Change `-p 3307:3307` with `-p 3307:3306`. The mapping pattern is `HOST:CONTAINER`. This way you are mapping port `3306` of container to host's `3307`.

Comment: @leopal I've tested before, but I've checked again and I still showing the "local" server databases (not docker). `docker ps` shows `0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   mariadb_develop`

Comment: What version of MariaDB?  I have succeeded with 10.0/1/2/3, but not .4 or .5.

Comment: @RickJames, right now I've tested with 10.3 but getting same behavior. Now, I used this command to run docker `sudo docker run -d -p 3307:3306 -v /var/lib/mysql-develop:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin --name mariadb_develop mariadb:10.3`